# Group generated by Coxeter groups of $B_8$ and $E_8$

Tags: gr.group-theory, coxeter-groups

Note: $B_8$, $D_8$, and $E_8$ are referring to the Coxeter groups.

What is the smallest group $G$ with the following properties?

- $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $E_8$.
- $G$ has a subgroup isomorphic to $B_8$.
- The intersection of the above two subgroups is isomorphic to $D_8$.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean?  I assume that you want to take a standard construction of root systems of these three types, where $B_8$ is $D_8$ plus some additional roots and $E_8$ is $D_8$ plus some different additional roots, and then you want to take the group generated reflections orthogonal to all of those roots.  Assuming that is what you mean, my initial description of the structure is "provably infinite and probably messy".

Comment: That’s not what I mean. I’m interested in the abstract group built using three groups which each happen to be isomorphic to reflection groups in $\mathbb{R}^8$. The geometry of the result is irrelevant.

Comment: That's fine, I don't insist on geometry, but we still need more information to understand what you're asking.  If we're thinking of these Coxeter groups as abstract groups, then each has a set of generators and some relations, and is a quotient of a free group on the generators (or is given by some universal property, if you prefer).  What relationship are you giving us between the groups of $B_8$ and $E_8$ so that we can make sense of the "group generated by" them as anything but a free product of groups?  Surely "intersecting in that of $D_8$" is a clue, but a clue that I don't understand.

Comment: I guess you mean an amalgamated product of the type $B_8$ and $E_8$ Coxeter groups, over some subgroup isomorphic to the type $D_8$ Coxeter group? Then it's an amalgamated product of finite groups, which is virtually free, so maybe "virtually free" counts as "the structure of the group"?

Comment: At the very least, you need to specify which embeddings of D_8 into the two larger Coxeter groups you want.

Comment: I’m looking for the smallest group which contains as a subgroupoid the set of all reflections mentioned by Nathan in his first comment.

Comment: @DanielSebald: There's a tension between your use of the terminology "reflection" and the terminology "abstract group". As an abstract group, Matt Zaremsky's comment gives you the answer (though, as I said, you need to specify the two embeddings of $D_8$). See here for further reading about amalgamated free products: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product#Generalization:_Free_product_with_amalgamation

Comment: @DanielSebald:  I am confused about the subgroupoid explanation in your earlier comment.  Assuming we are using the algebraic definition of groupoid in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groupoid, if we consider the set of reflections as a groupoid, the partial product is actually nowhere defined.  (The composition of two reflections is never a reflection.)  So that groupoid does not give any structure at all to the smallest group containing it.  If we want to have the reflections play any role at all, it seems like we just have to let them *generate* a group.

Comment: Okay, I rewrote my question entirely. Hopefully you can now understand it.

Comment: This is just a guess, but there are fairly standard ways to embed the $D_8$ root system into $B_8$ and into $E_8$. Namely: Let $e_1$, $e_2$, ..., $e_8$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^8$. We can identify $D_8$ with vectors of the form $\pm e_i \pm e_j$;  $B_8$ with $D_8$ together with $\pm e_j$ and $E_8$ with $D_8$ together with the $128$ vectors of the form $(\pm 1/2, \pm 1/2 , \ldots, \pm 1/2)$ and an even number of $-$ signs. Are you asking about the group generated by the reflections over $E_8$ and $B_8$ in that sense?

Comment: I think that one group $G$ satisfying the three bulleted conditions is $O_8^+(3)$, the group of isometries of an $8$-dimensional space over $F_3$ that contains an orthonormal basis. Whether it is "smallest" is another question.